# Where to put <label> around other html element or not?

Tags: html, css, label, forms

**Where to put  around other html element or not?**

**Option1- put around input element :**

```
<label>Url:
        <input type="text" size="350"/>
</label>
```

**Option2:**

```
<label>Url:</label>
<input type="text" size="350"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Option2 is invalid HTML. In that case, you must link the two tags together as it's impossible for the browser to know which label belongs to which field: `<label for="foo">...<input id="foo" ...>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The second is definitely better, it allows you to style separately.

You can also use the "for" attribute to bind it to an input field:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, in the first example the `<label>` is automatically linked to the `<input>`, while in the second example they are not (you must set the *for* and *id* attributes to emulate the former's behaviour).

Other than that, it's a matter of situation and preference. Personally I usually go for the former as there's less markup needed.

Comment: Even if you wrap the `<input>` in a `<label>` IE6 won't implicitly link them

Comment: it will if you use the for attribute in label, matching the id of the input. which is why they are there in the first place :)

Answer (score 6):

The latter. This way you can set style, width etc. without affecting `<input>`. It's also better semantically: The label is a label, and input is an input.